# How to create UEFI folder in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, uefi

I'm trying to create UEFI folder on my ubuntu 16.04 because my OS was created only for legacy, i wanted to use it on my laptop but the bios only boot UEFI

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/PZ6vYYQDV4/

Hope you guys could help me!

Comment: Welcome, what do you mean by *"my OS was create only for legacy"*?

Comment: Text should be included in the question not a picture.

Comment: 16.04 will be out of support this year, and you will need to upgrade.  Would suggest installing 18.04 or 20.04 on laptop.  Trying to change an OS from legacy to UEFI will usually lead to problems.  I am guessing that the laptop is a different computer than what you have 16.04 on.

Comment: Did this install come from different hardware?

Comment: @BrianTurek yes.

Comment: @David Apologize

Comment: @crip659 you're correct. Thank you for the advice. Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Does /boot/efi exist? If so, you are already in UEFI. If not, you must reinstall Ubuntu and make sure it is flagged with efi.

Comment: No, doesn't exist on the library. I tried boot-repair but it wont work. Thank you.

Comment: This means you can't upgrade to EFI. You can also look for the /sys/firmware/efi folder. If that exists, you can use EFI. To upgrade, you would need to make a partition formatted as FAT32. Make it at least 500MB. Then, you would need to mount it to /boot/efi. Also, Ubuntu now uses UEFI in at least up from 16.04.x to 20.10 or 21.04 (coming out soon.)

Comment: You can upgrade or change legacy to uefi but it wont work 100%.